# Value from a popup window in a parent element

Tags: jquery, select, input, popup, window

I have a document with an element like this:

```
<input type="text" id="newsPicture" name="newsPicture" />
```

With jQuery i created a link to show a PopUp window.

In this PopUp i have a list of news pictures like

```
<a id="newsPictureName" class="newsPicture">newsPictureName.jpg</a>
```

Now, i will select one of this pictures with an a-element to close the window

```
$(function(){
    $('.newsPicture').click(function() {
        window.close();
    });
});
```

How do i put the name of this newsPicture to the input-field in my parent document?

Any ideas?

Sorry for my bad english…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the element's text through [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

You can change the value of the field through using [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

That would make your code something like this

```
$(function(){
    $('.newsPicture').click(function() {
        window.close();

        //get the text of the element we clicked
        var pictureName = $(this).text();

        //put this value in our field
        $('#newsPicture').val(pictureName);
    });
});
```

or a shorter solution would be

```
$(function(){
    $('.newsPicture').click(function() {
        window.close();

        $('#newsPicture').val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But when i use this, i have many of a-elements with the same id namend "newsPicture" and i became an W3C error. When i change id (#) to class (.), it will not work.

Comment: For a start you are not allowed to have multiple elements with the same id.

Also… you are already using the class newspicture for your images. Just pick a different class like `.picturevalue`